# How can I fix my code so that it still deletes indentations, but doesn't delete numbers in tables, etc. in DXL?

Tags: richtext, ibm-doors

I am working on fixing a code that was developed to delete rich text from the database, but when I try to run it to delete only indentations, it tends to delete other formatting things such as bullet points, numbers in table, and numbers in other attributes. How can I fix this so it only deletes the indentations?

Here are a couple things that I tried:

1. I created a string that would read the object text of the current object it's being run through and used the following line of code in a cause where I wanted to get rid of indentations but keep bullets. I also looped this through a for richtext in string do.
   s = applyTextFormattingToParagraph(richText s, true, 0, 0)
   This code changed nothing with the outcome.
2. I also tried using rich text properties inside the if statement of removing identations but keeping bullets to reapply the bullets after they have been removed and this has done nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working example, am not fluent with RTF and did not try the following. Just a wild guess: perhaps you have to iterate over each RTP of each RT of the string and apply the text formatting to each single paragraph that you want to change?
Something like:

```
Object o
string richTextString
RichText rt
RichTextParagraph rtp

for o in module do {
  richTextString = richText (o."Object Text") // or other attribute containing RTF
  string newString = ""
  for rt in richTextString do {
    int paraNumber = 0
    for rtp in rt do {
      paraNumber++
      if (rtp.indentLevel > 0) {
        newString = newString applyTextFormattingToParagraph(rtp, rtp.isBullet, 0, paraNumber) 
      } else {
        newString = newString rtp
```

etc. etc. and finally set object text to the newString.

Comment: Hi Mike, this did not fix my issue.